# About to receive an offer and interested in different position at same company

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, internal-transfer

I'm currently in the final stages of applying for a job and I'm getting signals that I will very likely get an offer.

I was told that the position that I am interviewing for is a more of a transitionary position, and that I'm expected to be promoted/transferred to a different position in a year or so.

There are some other positions in this company that I would be interested in  being considered for. Would it be frowned upon to tell my recruiter about this?

Comment: The question is, are you interested in this one or not? Also, if you are interested in other positions, why don't you apply to them instead of this one?

Comment: Or are you saying that you hope that if you are eventually transferred you would prefer it to be to any of these positions you mention?

Comment: Interested in both, did not know about the other position until interviewer casually mentioned it. and yes to the second comment

Comment: Maybe you're just interested in the company and the types of jobs they offer. Could that be it?

Answer (score 4):

**Be transparent with the recruiter about the specific roles you are *and are not* interested in.**

If you are interested in positions other than the one you're being considered for, let the recruiter know. Letting him/her know sooner prevents wasted time and effort and gives them more opportunities to help you get those roles.

If you're interested in the role you're expecting an offer for *only* because you hope to be re-assigned, you should also let the recruiter and hiring manager know. Give the manager and recruiter as much opportunity as possible to make sure the future transfer will be feasible, and to alert you if it isn't something you should expect.

Regardless, **consider the immediate position on its own merits.** There is always a chance a future transfer or reassignment won't come through - make sure you'd feel good about your time invested in the role if promises/expectations aren't realized.

Answer (score 2):

Many employers are very supportive of internal promotions and hiring employees who are ambitious enough to have goals including long term career growth. It sounds like the employer you're talking to fits in that category.

That said, employers are trying to balance that with **filling an immediate need in a specific role.** If they're hiring you as a Basketweaver's Apprentice, it's because they need a Basketweaver's Apprentice, not because *you* want to some day be a Basket Supply Chain Manager.

So - if your employer is talking about their strategies for promoting from within, **consider that a long term benefit** and not an immediate, risk free plan. In other words, don't take the Apprentice job only because you want to some day be a Supply Chain Manager. However, since *they* have initiated the conversation about being promoted to other positions, it's completely acceptable (and probably a good idea) to discuss which other positions you may want to pursue in the future. By doing so, you're showing that you will fit their culture well, and you're ambitious enough to want to grow. Just make sure you're doing it within the context of also being committed to the *actual* position you've applied for, and showing interest in, and skills required for, doing that specific role.

In other words, don't let the promise of future promotion get you too carried away.

Comment: Worth noting that some workplaces will tell terrible, terrible lies about potential future openings... and others will simply be over-optimistic about positions that are not in any way guaranteed to materialize.

Comment: That's very true, which is another reason to focus on the opportunity at hand and make sure you actually want it.